# Authorize Instagram App via terminal while generating access token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Requesting an access-token for Instagram App needs user to hit some url, and then log-in and then click on Authorize button. Is there any way to get this done without anyone intervening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not possible without redirecting to Instagram login page.

Here is documentation for authentication:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/